# How can I apply a CSS style to the whole row in a grid?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I have a grid with rows and columns, each line forms a kind of section. I would like to apply a shadow to each row but not to every element of the row. I would like to do it for the whole row.

I tried to encapsulate the rows in a "div" but it deconstructs the structure of the grid (unless we use "display: contents" but it doesn't work to apply a shadow).

**I would have liked to know if it is possible to wrap elements of a grid without breaking its structure?**

[Picture of a row of my grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P99od.jpg) (I would like to apply a shadow to the white block).

[image]

Something that would probably look like that:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row-wrapper">
  <div class="column1"></div>
  <div class="column2"></div>
  <div class="column3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row-wrapper{
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.05);
}
```

[Here is the original code (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/b7xd63Lv/)

Comment: I'm not seeing any output from your HTML and CSS snippets. What code did you use to get the grid in your picture?

Comment: I did not put them because the image is only a part of the page and the original CSS and HTML codes are quite long but the structure respects the mentioned one.

Comment: Could you give me enough of the code so that I can at least reproduce the data grid? It's hard for me to try to solve the problem without it.

Comment: I edited the post, you can find the complete code on JSFiddle (CSS and HTML).

Comment: Why don't you sue semantic html instead? with table, th and tr, you will be able to make a semantic distinction between rows

Comment: I used "grid" rather than a table mainly for its "responsive" ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer: taking a wild guess that you are using css-grid.**

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knhgcom8/)

[CSS-Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

gist:

```
<style>
  .header { grid-area: header; margin: 0.5rem; padding: 0.5rem; }
  .label-1 { grid-area: label-1; }
  .value-1 { grid-area: value-1; }
  .label-2 { grid-area: label-2; }
  .value-2 { grid-area: value-2; }
  .action { grid-area: action; }

  .row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header header header header header"
      "label-1 value-1 value-1 label-2 value-2 value-2 action";
    background-color: whitesmoke;
  }

  .rows, .row {
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
      0 0.5rem 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0.5rem; margin: 0.5rem; padding: 0.5rem;
  }
</style>

<div class="rows">
  <div class="header">Data</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="label-1"><label for="r1mass">Mass</label></div>
    <div class="value-1"><input id="r1mass" type="text" /></div>
    <div class="label-2"><label for="r1species">Species</label></div>
    <div class="value-2"><input id="r1species" type="text" /></div>
    <div class="action"><button>+</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="label-1"><label for="r2mass">Mass</label></div>
    <div class="value-1"><input id="r2mass" type="text" /></div>
    <div class="label-2"><label for="r2species">Species</label></div>
    <div class="value-2"><input id="r2species" type="text" /></div>
    <div class="action"><button>+</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I edited the post, you can find the complete code on JSFiddle (CSS and HTML). I did not use "areas", is it possible to do without?